# mPDF - PHP script inside the html block of code to generate PDF file

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, pdf-generation, mpdf

As follows in the script, I need to insert PHP script inside the html code and I didn't find any example in the documentation that shows how to do that.

Is that possible?

- I use WordPress
- I use WooCommerce
- I must print the thankyou Page. On the thankyou page I have a button that I click and download the file.
- The PHP file that generate the PDF file must receive dynamic data.
- The PHP script must be included inside the html code as follows.

When I click on the button to download the PDF file, I got the following error message:

> **Notice:** Undefined variable: order in **C:\xampppserver2\htdocs\mrdigital\wp-content\themes\astra-child\testmpdf.php** on line **22**
>
> **Fatal error:** Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_order_number() on null in C:\xampppserver2\htdocs\mrdigital\wp-content\themes\astra-child\testmpdf.php:22 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in **C:\xampppserver2\htdocs\mrdigital\wp-content\themes\astra-child\testmpdf.php** on line **22**

This is line 22: `$order = $_GET[$order->get_order_number()];`

This is the whole **testmpdf.php** file:

```
<?php
/**
 * @Author: exame
 * @Last Modified time: 2020-11-05 15:47:01
 */
use Mpdf\Mpdf;

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$mpdf = new Mpdf();

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/custom/temp/dir/path']);

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
    'mode' => 'utf-8',    
    'orientation' => 'P',
    'format' => 'A4'
]);

$order = $_GET[$order->get_order_number()]; 
$order = $_GET[$order->get_date_created()]; 

$html = '
<div id="pdfprintcontentarea">
                    <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--success woocommerce-thankyou-order-received">Obrigado. Seu pedido foi recebido. Enviamos o comprovante de compra por e-mail para você.</p>
            <p>Tempo de Reserva do Pedido: <b>24 horas</b> - Por favor efetue o pagamento agora antes que você perca a reserva!</p>
            <ul class="woocommerce-order-overview woocommerce-thankyou-order-details order_details">

            <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__order order">
                
                <strong>$order->get_order_number();</strong>
            </li>
                            
            <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__date date">
                Hora:                   <strong>10:56:01.507644</strong>
            </li>

            <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__date date">                  
                    <strong>wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() );</strong>
            </li>

                
            <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__total total">
                    Total:                  <strong><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">R$</span>5,00</bdi></span></strong>
            </li>

                <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__total total">
                    Status Pedido:                  <strong>Aguardando</strong>
                </li>

                                    <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__payment-method method">
                        Método de pagamento:                        <strong>Transferência Bancária Rápida e Gratuita pelo Aplicativo do Banco</strong>
                    </li>
</div> <!-- <div id="pdfprintcontentarea"> -->
';

//$html = file_get_contents(__DIR__. '/woocommerce/checkout/thankyou.php');
$mpdf->SetProtection(array(),'','MyPassword');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY);// Load the html
$mpdf->Output('invoice.pdf',"D");
$mpdf->cleanup();
```

How can I turn around this situation?

Comment: The button you click, can we have a look at the code, where is it hooked and all? seems like you need to parse the order id to the php script.

Comment: hi @Precious-Omonze  
This is the button  
`

function pila_print_button_thankyou() {

    echo'<button type="button" id="cmd">PDF</button>';
}

add_action('woocommerce_before_thankyou','cincopila_print_print_area');

`

Comment: Where does this button go to exactly? cause it seems like it doesn't carry any data.

Comment: Says in your error notice... `$order` is not defined. so `$order = $_GET[$order->get_order_number()];` is impossible.

Comment: Well said @helgatheviking! And what should i do please? Should i call the WC_Order object inside the file? i've already tried that.

Comment: You need to instantiate an order object. `$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );` but you do also need to define the order ID somehow.

Comment: @helgatheviking, Well I tried this and get a error message:  
// Get an instance of the WC_Order object
`$order = wc_get_order($order_id); // Line 29`  ,

`$order_id = '';`  

**Error Message**

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wc_get_order() in C:\xampppserver2\htdocs\mrdigital\wp-content\themes\astra-child\testmpdf.php:29 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampppserver2\htdocs\mrdigital\wp-content\themes\astra-child\testmpdf.php on line 29`

Comment: You should maybe make sure WC is loaded before you run the code. you can hook it to `woocommerce_before_thankyou`

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it after `wc_get_order` has been created, and also, find an easy way to get the order id. this is my proposed solution below.

```
<?php
/**
 * @Author: exame
 * @Last Modified time: 2020-11-05 15:47:01
 */
use Mpdf\Mpdf;

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';



function pekky_print_pdf( $order_id ) {
$mpdf = new Mpdf();

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/custom/temp/dir/path']);

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
    'mode' => 'utf-8',    
    'orientation' => 'P',
    'format' => 'A4'
]);

$order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); 

$html = '
<div id="pdfprintcontentarea">
                    <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--success woocommerce-thankyou-order-received">Obrigado. Seu pedido foi recebido. Enviamos o comprovante de compra por e-mail para você.</p>
            <p>Tempo de Reserva do Pedido: <b>24 horas</b> - Por favor efetue o pagamento agora antes que você perca a reserva!</p>
            <ul class="woocommerce-order-overview woocommerce-thankyou-order-details order_details">

            <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__order order">
                
                <strong>$order->get_order_number();</strong>
            </li>
                            
            <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__date date">
                Hora:                   <strong>10:56:01.507644</strong>
            </li>

            <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__date date">                  
                    <strong>wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() );</strong>
            </li>

                
            <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__total total">
                    Total:                  <strong><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">R$</span>5,00</bdi></span></strong>
            </li>

                <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__total total">
                    Status Pedido:                  <strong>Aguardando</strong>
                </li>

                                    <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__payment-method method">
                        Método de pagamento:                        <strong>Transferência Bancária Rápida e Gratuita pelo Aplicativo do Banco</strong>
                    </li>
</div> <!-- <div id="pdfprintcontentarea"> -->
';

//$html = file_get_contents(__DIR__. '/woocommerce/checkout/thankyou.php');
$mpdf->SetProtection(array(),'','MyPassword');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY);// Load the html
$mpdf->Output('invoice.pdf',"D");
$mpdf->cleanup();
}

// Hook to a woo func.
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_thankyou', 'pekky_print_pdf', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for the help.
This is how i have turned around the situation.

**1°** You need to know that i customised my **mPDF Composer installation** inside my Template-Child and **NOT** inside the Default Root Folder.

**2°** I must definitivily to make reference to the Wordpress **wp-config.php** file, other wise this never would worked because of my customised installation.

**3°** I must definitivily to make reference to the Woocommerce Class **class-wc-order.php** file.

**4°** Now as follows in the code, i can receive the **order object** and manipulate what i need.

**Code:**

```
<?php

// Root Directory WP Config
require_once '/xampppserver2/htdocs/mrdigital/wp-config.php';   

// Root Directory CLASS WC ORDER
require_once '../../plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-order.php';   

// Load MPDF Loader
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Mpdf\Mpdf;

$mpdf = new Mpdf();
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/custom/temp/dir/path']);
```

```
$order = new WC_Order($_GET['key']);
```