# How to begin customizing mpdf using composer inside a WordPress Child theme, I used the "mpdf.github.io" docs

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php, mpdf

May I ask, I am using WP contact form 7 and it's associating plugins to run a feature were all submissions are extracted and compiled to be sent to the designated user email, I am just curious, I am following the composer installation same as you, I have it installed inside my child template, I am using this "https://mpdf.github.io/" as my docs to customize the header and footer done by this plugin "Generate PDF using Contact Form 7" I'd like to get an idea, were I should begin to add my scripts for the customization of overriding the PDF default template e.g Header and footer etc ....

Here is my setup wp-content/themes/autocardivi/mpdf/

in that mpdf/ directory I have composer setup and the following files it has are:

vendor/

composer.json

composer.lock

package.json

What I want to know is where do I add this script to begin my customization?

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir' => DIR . '/custom/temp/dir/path']);

I found a case related to this - [mPDF - PHP Script inside the html block of code to generate PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64703771/mpdf-php-script-inside-the-html-block-of-code-to-generate-pdf-file) - I wonder how he was able to use composer and modify mPDF

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? How is this problem related to Composer?

Comment: I don't know how to explain this, I want to edit the default PDF using composer, is there such thing as Wordpress using Composer?

Comment: The "Generate PDF using Contact Form 7" plugin using Composer based on it's documentation for   Docs url: https://mpdf.github.io/